# What is the difference between sigmoid functions inplemented in tensorflow and that from scratch

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, neural-network

What is the difference in the implementation of the numerically stable sigmoid function and that implemented in TensorFlow?

I am getting different results while implementing these two functions `sigmoid()` and `tf.nn.sigmoid()` (or `tf.sigmoid()`). The first one gives `nan` and a very bad accuracy (around 0.93%) while the second one gives a very good accuracy (around 99.99%).

The numerically stable sigmoid function, `sigmoid()`, is given by:

```py
def sigmoid(z):
    return tf.where(z >= 0, 1 / (1 + tf.exp(-z)), tf.exp(z) / (1 + tf.exp(z)))
```

I expect to get the same results (accuracy) for both approaches, whether that one implemented by TensorFlow or that one created from scratch `sigmoid()`.

**Note**: I tested the two functions `tf.sigmoid` and `sigmoid()` with same model.

Comment: What input is giving you NaN?

Comment: Thanks, @DavisHerring. The test cost after `i` epochs. it might be in my case when `epoch = 11` he test `cost = NaN`

Comment: To exactly see what's happening in the tf.nn.sigmoid method, you can open the module and view the source code if some extra modifications are made with it.

Comment: Thanks, @ShubhamPanchal. Unfortunately, I couldn't find where they define the `sigmoid` function from scratch. it is mentioned in the docstring `y = 1 / (1 + exp(-x))` but I tried implementing this but still don't get the expected score.

Answer (score 1):

I tried reproducing your case with below code with simple Iris Dataset. Value of `l` is the `cost` calculated using `tf.sigmoid` and the value of `l2` is the `cost (cost2)` calculated using your custom `sigmoid` function and the values of `l` and `l2` are almost the same for me.

We can dig deeper into this if you could provide code and the data (if it can be shared).

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn import model_selection
import sys

iris_data = pd.read_csv('iris_species/Iris.csv',header=0,delimiter = ',')

data_set_y = pd.DataFrame(iris_data['Species'])
data_set_X = iris_data.drop(['Species'],axis=1)
num_samples = iris_data.shape[0]
num_features = iris_data.shape[1]
num_labels = 1

X = tf.placeholder('float',[None,4])
y = tf.placeholder('float',[None,1])

W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([4,2]),dtype=tf.float32)
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1]),dtype=tf.float32)

train_X,test_X,train_y,test_y = model_selection.train_test_split(data_set_X,data_set_y,random_state=0)

train_y = np.reshape(train_y,(-1,1))

prediction = tf.add(tf.matmul(X,W),b)
cost = tf.sigmoid(prediction)
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.001).minimize(cost)
num_epochs = 1000

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    for epoch in range(num_epochs):
        _,l = sess.run([optimizer,cost],feed_dict = {X: train_X, y: train_y})
        if epoch % 50 == 0:
            #print (type(l))
            #print (l.shape)
            print (l)


def sigmoid(z):
    return tf.where(z >= 0, 1 / (1 + tf.exp(-z)), tf.exp(z) / (1 + tf.exp(z)))

prediction = tf.add(tf.matmul(X,W),b)
cost2 = sigmoid(prediction)
optimizer2 = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.001).minimize(cost2)
num_epochs = 1000


print ('Shape of train_y is: ',train_y.shape)


with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    for epoch in range(num_epochs):
        _,l2 = sess.run([optimizer2,cost2],feed_dict = {X: train_X, y: train_y})
        if epoch % 50 == 0:
            #print (type(l))
            #print (l.shape)
            print (l2)
```